# How can I send tweets to my Twitter account?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, twitter-oauth

Every time the user post a comments, I want it to send the same comment to my Twitter automatically.

First of all, I have it already done with Twitter developer settings.

So I made a test action in my App to make it send a tweet to my Twitter account.
However, it says this error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/top_controller.rb:173:in `test_action'
```

How can I solve this? These are my codes

**gems related that are already bundled** (I'm on rails 3.2.11)

```
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'twitter'
gem 'figaro'
```

**config/initializers/omniauth.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, ENV['TWITTER_KEY'], ENV['TWITTER_SECRET']
    Twitter.configure do |config|
        config.consumer_key = ENV["TWITTER_KEY"]
        config.consumer_secret = ENV["TWITTER_SECRET"]
    end
end
```

**config/application.yml**

```
TWITTER_KEY: 6TeBX6HkeHzMXesgc
TWITTER_SECRET: JyfOndg8xHcM81KEpgmBT7h2vFJJujMP14YTdt6ruvLbsQk
```

**test_action**

```
def test_action  
    @twitter = Twitter::Client.new(oauth_token: request.env["omniauth.auth"][:credentials][:token], oauth_token_secret: request.env["omniauth.auth"][:credentials][:secret])
    @twitter.update("Your message")
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully tweeted on your account."
    redirect_to root_path
    return 
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue may be with your controller configuration of Twitter:

instead of:

```
@twitter = Twitter::Client.new(oauth_token: request.env["omniauth.auth"][:credentials][:token], oauth_token_secret: request.env["omniauth.auth"][:credentials][:secret])
```

try this:

```
@twitter = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key = ENV['CONSUMER_KEY']
  config.consumer_secret = ENV['CONSUMER_SECRET']
  config.access_token = request.env["omniauth.auth"][:credentials][:token]
  config.access_token_secret = request.env["omniauth.auth"][:credentials][:secret]
end
```

You also might want to confirm that your API keys have read and write permissions, which you can check on your Twitter developer account [here](https://apps.twitter.com/).